# Best way to use multiple shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Few weeks I learn OpenGL on famous http://learnopengl.com and have question about a organise multiple materials (shaders).
In this tutorial is using Shader class which compose Shader program from list of vert/frag shaders:

```
Shader shader("vert.glsl", "frag.glsl");
```

After that for shader I create uniforms:

```
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
etc.
```

And at the end we receive one Shader program. How in this case I can make multiple shaders? 
I try to make:

```
Shader shader("vertDiff.glsl", "fragDiff.glsl");
Shader shaderGlass ("vertGlass.glsl", "fragGlass.glsl");
Shader shaderLight("vertLight.glsl", "fragLight.glsl")
```

And after that i make uniforms for .glsl for each shader :

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderGlass.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
```

But shading doesn't work correctly. The same uniforms needs to be declared few times for each shader and that make program incorrect.
How is a correctly to make this part? Thank you and sorry for my stupid question.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course that doesn't work. The `glUniform*` calls change the *currently bound* program's uniform state. So whatever program was passed to `glUseProgram` most recently.

If you want to modify a uniform in another program, you have to switch to the other program. Or [use `glProgramUniform*`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glProgramUniform.xhtml).